# How to convert javax.xml.transform.Source into an InputStream?

Tags: java, io, transform

How can I convert a `javax.xml.transform.Source` into a InputStream? The Implementation of `Source` is `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource`.

```
Source inputSource = messageContext.getRequest().getPayloadSource();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First try to downcast to `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource`. If that succeeds you have access to the underlying `InputStream` or `Reader` through getters. This would be the easiest way.

If downcasting fails, you can try using a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to transform it into a `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult` that has been setup with a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then you return a `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`. Something like:

```
Transformer t = // getTransformer();
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result result = new StreamResult(os);
t.transform(inputSource, result);
return new ByteArrayInputStream(os.getByteArray());
```

Of course, if the `StreamSource` can be a large document, this is not advisable. In that case, you could use a temporary file and `java.io.FileOutputStream`/`java.io.FileInputStram`. Another option would be to spawn a transformer thread and communicate through `java.io.PipedOutputStream`/`java.io.PipedInputStream`, but this is more complex:

```
PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);
Result result = new StreamResult(os);
// This creates and starts a thread that creates a transformer
// and applies it to the method parameters.
spawnTransformerThread(inputSource, result);
return is;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not normally possible, unless it can be down-casted to [StreamSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) or other [implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html).