# Source to ByteSource

Tags: java, guava, javax.xml

The API I'm working with takes in a `com.google.common.io.ByteSource`. My API takes in a `javax.xml.transform.Source` since I'm doing `Schema` validation as well as calling the other API. Is there a clean way to convert from a `Source` to a `ByteSource` and/or there is a better object to take in that would meet both methods' needs (i.e. ByteSource and Source).

Comment: Sounds like a job for the adapter pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711239/how-to-convert-javax-xml-transform-source-into-an-inputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ByteSource](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html#openBufferedStream%28%29) can give an InputStream which can be used for the transformation using `ByteSource.openBufferedStream`.

Comment: I ended up changing my API to take in a ByteSource and went with this approach. Not the prettiest, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ByteSource` and `Source` don't seem like particularly compatible APIs:

- `Source` doesn't appear to be a source of bytes, in general. There are multiple implementations and only one can (`StreamSource`) provides an `InputStream` for reading bytes.
- Even `StreamSource` does not appear to be compatible with the expected contract of a `ByteSource`. It looks like `StreamSource` is basically a wrapper around a single `InputStream` and/or `Reader`, while `ByteSource` is expected to be able to return a new, independent `InputStream` each time `openStream()` is called.

Is there not a version of the API you're working with that takes an `InputStream` rather than a `ByteSource`? It's typical (or should be, anyway) for there to exist both versions of a method.